# Why does WebBrowser.InvokeScript not work the same as using the console with the same script?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a c# application that gets the current song information being played from a pandora playlist.

Currently the code I am using in the Chrome Console is,

```
document.querySelector('.playerBarSong').innerText;
```

And that returns the title of the song. But when i translate that code over to a WebBrowser control in c# using:

```
var artist = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("document.querySelector('.playerBarSong').innerText");
```

but that only returns a blank string. Am I calling the InvokeScript improperly?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Maybe instead of focusing on PEOPLE BEING NICE, you could actually... i don't know... answer the question? I don't understand why being nice is dealt with in such a harsh manner.

Comment: Have you tried other attributes? `textContent`, `innerHTML` ? Are they empty too?

Comment: @ChrisCurtis: learn how the site works before you start complaining about people who have been here for, say, four years. It's not a discussion forum. We're not having a nice conversation. We're not having a conversation at all. Nice is not necessary - in fact, it distracts from the reason we _are_ here: for you to ask a question, and to get answers.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: One line is not going to distract someone IMO. That is just a sad excuse... but whatever. I solved the problem.

Comment: @ChrisCurtis: I guess you didn't read the link I posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that pandora makes the song information a link

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in webBrowser1.Document.Links)
    if (link.InnerHtml != null)
        listBox1.Items.Add(" " + link.InnerHtml);
```

That puts them all into a listBox, which i can then just pull the static slot of 21,22,and 23 for the song title, artist, and album